# "Message me whenever you thought you needed/need help?"

Tags: tense, conditionals

> Message me whenever you thought you needed/need help?

What is the exact grammar called? Is it conditional or the conditional would be like “If you thought you needed help...”?

Secondly, should it be needed or need?

Comment: The sentence is nonsense. An imperative (message me)  which refers to an action in the future, cannot be meaningfully applied to the period immediately following an action in the past (you thought).

Answer (score 1):

I believe what is meant here is better said with:

```
Message me whenever you need help.
```

As pointed out in a comment, the sentence gives instruction to someone to do something in the future, so basing it on something in past tense ('thought', 'needed') is a little confusing.

The revised sentence keeps the implication that the person to whom this is said or sent is being encouraged to do it multiple times if they need to -- if it said "Message me when you need help.", it would look a little more as if the speaker only intended that to happen one time, though it does not exclude it happening multiple times. But by using "whenever", the speaker indicates that there might be more than one time when help is needed, and that the person spoken to should send a message each of those times.

Comment: I agree, the original sentence would only make sense as part of a longer, sentence such as "_I hoped_ you would message me whenever you thought you needed help". It's still a bit strange but, because both the hoping and messaging are in the past, the tenses are consistent. An imperative sentence with an instruction in the past tense would only make sense if someone had a time machine!

Comment: Thank you. I think I’ve gotten to bring the usage of Conditional sentences to present .
But a question, you said that it might sound confusing but is it actually something to be used? Do you think there’s any structure like this that I’ve confused it with the sentence I typed?

Comment: And if I want to use it with `if`, shall I say, “If you ever need help, message me.”? I think this seems a bit awkward. I feel like saying “If you ever needed help, message me.” 

Comment: Or I’d better say, “If you shall ever need my help, message me.”?

Comment: @BoldBen Hello. Yeah, most probably, I think I’ve gotten the structure from those conditional sentence structures.

Comment: Alternately, "If you think you need help, message me."

Comment: @JHTAOQ My apologies for not getting back here. Certainly you could have heard the original construction used -- native English speakers don't always use correct verb tense. Using either "ever need help" or "ever needed help" in those two sentences is correct. "If you shall ever need my help" is not a natural construction; it sounds a little like formal language from colonial times, though I am not knowledgeable about that.